# Associated models in a Sencha Touch 2 application

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch

I am working in a Sencha Touch app and with associated models

Parent model:

```
Ext.define('xx.model.TemplateModel', {
  extend      : 'Ext.data.Model',
  requires    : [
    'xx.model.BrandsModel'
  ],
  config      : {
    useCache    : false,
    idProperty: 'templates',
    fields      : [
      {
        name: 'id',
        type: 'string'
      },
      {
        name: 'name',
        type: 'string'
      },
      {
        name: 'validFrom',
        type: 'auto'
      },
      {
        name: 'validTo',
        type: 'auto'
      }
    ]
  },
  associations: [
    {
      type           : 'hasMany',
      associatedModel: 'xx.model.BrandsModel',
      ownerModel     : 'xx.model.TemplateModel',
      autoLoad       : true,
      associationKey : 'brands'
    }
  ]
});
```

and associated model:

```
Ext.define('xx.model.BrandsModel', {
  extend  : 'Ext.data.Model',
  requires: [],
  config  : {
    useCache    : false,
    idProperty: 'Brands',
    fields      : [
      {
        name: 'brandId',
        type: 'string'
      },
      {
        name: 'brandText',
        type: 'string'
      }

    ]
  }
});
```

First point, this implementation is in the correct way?, because I cannot see this associated model when I am debugging in the chrome console.

Second point, What would it be the correct way to test this and to see the records?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would have expected that it throws an error:

- You have no "brands" field on your template model, but have specified the associationKey to be brands
- You have not specified a primaryKey on the association although you use a modified idProperty on the BrandsModel

Also, please have a look at the example in the [API docs](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.data.association.HasMany) how to lessen your code by using readable shortcuts.

Comment: But I am adding like required model to the parent model, can you show me an example?